# Repository pattern in Rust

Tags: rust, repository

I'm looking to add a thin layer of abstraction for database interaction in my application. I'm not really looking for a full blown ORM or advanced query builder.

I am familiar with [Diesel](http://diesel.rs/), but its current limitations (for my specific use case) require almost as much effort to workaround as using Rust's database adapters directly.

### What I have

My repository interface looks like:

```
pub trait Repository {            

    // I know I could probably add the `Sized` constraint to the trait directly
    // but wasn't sure if I wanted to do that yet
    fn find<T, Find>(conn: &mut T, id: u64) 
        -> ::err::Result<Find> where T: ::db::GenConn, Find: Findable<Self>, Self: Sized {
        let tup: Find::RowType = conn.prep_exec(Find::SQL, (id,))?
            .flat_map(|x| x)
            .flat_map(|x| ::mysql::from_row_opt(x))
            .next()
            .ok_or("No results")?;
        Ok(Find::from_row(tup))
    }

    fn insert<T, Ins>(conn: &mut T, obj: Ins) 
        -> ::err::Result<u64> where T: ::db::GenConn, Ins: Insertable<Self>, Self: Sized {
        let res = conn.prep_exec(Ins::SQL, obj.to_params())?;
        let id = res.last_insert_id();
        Ok(id)
    }

    fn update<T, Up>(conn: &mut T, obj: Up) 
        -> ::err::Result<()> where T: ::db::GenConn, Up: Updatable<Self>, Self: Sized {
        let res = conn.prep_exec(Up::SQL, obj.to_params())?;
        Ok(())
    }

    fn delete<T, Del>(conn: &mut T, obj: Del) 
        -> ::err::Result<()> where T: ::db::GenConn, Del::Deletable<Self>, Self: Sized {
        let res = conn.prep_exec(Del::SQL, obj.to_params())?;
        Ok(())
    }    
}

pub trait Insertable<R: Repository> {
    const SQL: &'static str;
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params;
}

pub trait Updatable<R: Repository> {
    const SQL: &'static str;
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params;
}

pub trait Findable<R: Repository> {
    const SQL: &'static str;
    type RowType: ::mysql::value::FromRow;
    fn from_row(row: Self::RowType) -> Self;
}

pub trait Deletable<R: Repository> {
    const SQL: &'static str;
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params;
}
```

Which I can implement like:

```
pub enum ClipRepository {}

impl Repository for ClipRepository {}

impl<'a> Insertable<ClipRepository> for &'a NewClip {
    const SQL: &'static str = 
        "INSERT INTO clips(slug, data, interview_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params {
        (&self.slug, &self.data, &self.interview_id).into()
    }
}

impl<'a> Updatable<ClipRepository> for &'a Clip {
    const SQL: &'static str = 
        "UPDATE clips SET slug = ?, data = ?, interview_id = ? WHERE id = ?";
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params {
        (&self.slug, &self.data, &self.interview_id, &self.id).into()
    }
}

impl Findable<ClipRepository> for Clip {
    const SQL: &'static str = 
        "SELECT id, slug, data, interview_id FROM clips WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
    type RowType = (u64, String, clips::Data, u64);
    fn from_row(tup: Self::RowType) -> Self {
        Clip { id: tup.0, slug: tup.1, data: tup.2, interview_id: tup.3 }
    }
}

impl Deletable<ClipRepository> for Clip {
    const SQL: &'static str = 
        "DELETE FROM clips WHERE id = ?";
    fn to_params(&self) -> ::mysql::Params {
        (&self.id,).into()
    }
}
```

And which I can use like:

```
let mut conn = ::db::DB.get()?;
let clip: Clip = Repository::find(&mut *conn, id)?;
```

### What I like about this

- This is boilerplate, but a manageable amount, and it moves the SQL/database logic out of my data models
- It keeps the query SQL and the ToValue/FromValue data together. Most of the Rust database adapters provide ways to look up row values by column name (e.g. `row.get("id")`, but these typically come with a lookup penalty (admittedly very small). This allows me to use the select order without too much danger of mixing up fields.

### Questions

This seems like a useful abstraction, but I haven't seen anything like it in my (certainly limited) exposure to Rust code. Am I missing some major flaw? Or is it just that orphan rules make packaging this as a crate way less powerful/useful?

Are there better ways to abstract the repository pattern? I kind of felt like I was making up the signatures as I went along.

Comment: Repositories should deal with domain-model objects, not database entities. Domain-model objects can be aggregates of several database entities. For example, an Invoice in the context of a domain model, can actually be composed of two database entities, a Invoice "header" and several InvoiceLine entities. I'm researching a similar approach where so far, I have a Repository like you do, except it holds domain model objects, and then several DAO's that deal with persistence or more precisely, constitute the DAL (Data Access Layer) Service.

Comment: Main problem I can think of is that you have to define impl Insertable in same crate as entity Clip, also it's not possible to define different queries for different RDBMS